# graphic.clear does not clear surface to transparent color

Tags: c#, winforms

Why doesn't `graphic.clear(Color.Transparent)` clear surface to transparent and makes black background?
How to clear the surface of control without any background?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear graphics on a transparent control in windows forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609032/how-to-clear-graphics-on-a-transparent-control-in-windows-forms)

Answer (score -1):

if you want real use Transparent color you must use API WPF it's only one way.